# What's the difference between QString[] and QStringList

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, qstring, qtcore

What's the difference between an object of QStringList and an Array of QStrings? I mean it seems that both behave as an array.

Comment: Did you [read the docs](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qstringlist.html)?

Comment: The difference is the same as the difference between a QStringList and a QStringList[] array.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`QStringList` is a dynamic array, meaning that it can expand/shrink as you add more/remove strings to/from it.

`QString array[10];` is a fixed size array of `QString`. You can't expand or shrink it.